# How to enable multitouch in cocos2d-x ios game using c++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I want to enable multitouch mode in cocos2d-x using c++.There are answers related to how to enable it on cocos2d but I want to enable it in cocos2d-x.Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself got the answer.In order to enable multitouch just go to your AppController.mm
then in the function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions after creating the EAGL View just add the following code.

```
[__glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```

So now the function should look like this

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary      
*)launchOptions {

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
EAGLView *__glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame: [window bounds]
                                 pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                 depthFormat: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16
                          preserveBackbuffer: NO
                                  sharegroup: nil
                               multiSampling: NO
                             numberOfSamples:0 ];

[__glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
// Use RootViewController manage EAGLView
viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
viewController.view = __glView;
//continued.....
```

Answer (score 1):

For other platforms this should be on by default but for iOS you need to enable it. As of Cocos2d-x 3.16, modify a single line of the `RootViewController.mm` generated by the `cocos new` commandline tool to enable multi-touch.

```
--- a/proj.ios_mac/ios/RootViewController.mm
+++ b/proj.ios_mac/ios/RootViewController.mm
@@ -52,7 +52,7 @@
                                      numberOfSamples: 0 ];

     // Enable or disable multiple touches
-    [eaglView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
+    [eaglView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
```